# How to custom layout h:selectOneRadio

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsf

the layout of h:selectOneRadio can either go horizontal or vertical, so is there a way that I can do some custom layout. For example, instead of displaying 8 radio button, display them in 2 rows with 4 on each row? Please provide your answer beside PrimeFaces p:selectOneRadio solution, it use CSS3 causing IE8 to display the radio button in rectangle shape.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150717/breaking-up-radio-buttons-into-columns-in-jsf/1152921

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not exactly that, but you could use [Tomahawk's](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/index.html) [`<t:selectOneRadio>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_selectOneRadio.html) with the `layout` attribute set to `"spread"` to have a markupless rendering of radio buttons. You can then use [`<t:radio>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_radio.html) to place the individual radio buttons in the markup the way you want, such as in a `<h:panelGrid columns="4">`.

E.g.

```
<t:selectOneRadio id="foo" value="#{bean.selectedItem}" layout="spread">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
</t:selectOneRadio>

<h:panelGrid columns="4">
    <t:radio for="foo" index="0" />
    <t:radio for="foo" index="1" />
    <t:radio for="foo" index="2" />
    <t:radio for="foo" index="3" />

    <t:radio for="foo" index="4" />
    <t:radio for="foo" index="5" />
    <t:radio for="foo" index="6" />
    <t:radio for="foo" index="7" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

or even when the amount of radio buttons is unspecified

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4">
    <c:forEach items="#{bean.availableItems}" varStatus="loop">
        <t:radio for="foo" index="#{loop.index}" />
    </c:forEach>
</h:panelGrid>
```

*(note that `<ui:repeat>` is not suitable as it runs during view render time and thus end up as a single column of `<h:panelGrid>`, you'd need to use plain HTML `<table>` instead)*

Comment: Thank you very much :) Tomhawk works for now, but when I download Tomhawk via mvn, it downloaded so many extra jar files, which seems a bit overkill to me. I see you have a tutorial about styling selectOneMenu by extend MenuRenderer, I will take a look at it, maybe it will help me create a custom selectOneRadio component. Thank you very much

Comment: Tomahawk is open source, you could also take a peek in it. Yes, it comes with a whole bunch of dependencies. For alone the `t:selectOneRadio`, just those Apache Commons dependencies are sufficient, all others are unnecessary.

Comment: Yup, it does come with lots of dependencies. We add dependencies to our app via maven, and i do `<groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomahawk20</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.13</version>`, it comes with a whole lot, is there a way to avoid this, BalusC?

Comment: Thank you, you have been very helpful, I will expose this to the maven community.