# More than 1 row with h:selectmanyCheckbox

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, selectmanycheckbox

I have a list of 16 items which should be shown like this

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
etc.
```

4 Items in a row and then it should add another row.

My problem is that your only allowed to show the info like

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 etc
```

or

```
1
2
3
4
etc.
```

My code looks like this:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{main.selectedStates}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{main.stateOutput}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

I have absolutely no idea how this should work. I spent now like 2 hours searching it on Google.

PS: Please don't blame me for my english :P

Comment: There is no native JSF component that will support what you want. However, you can make your own look 'n feel using `<ui:repeat>` and `<h:selectOneCheckBox>` tag components.

Comment: Similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255509/how-to-custom-layout-hselectoneradio and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150717/breaking-up-radio-buttons-into-columns-in-jsf/1152921 but for radios

Comment: I solved it by making 4 lists and display them vertically

Answer (score 0):

A non intrusive solution would be to use some JavaScript to modify the HTML DOM after the DOM tree has loaded. Something like, pseudo-code:

```
someSelectorForCheckboxDiv.forEach( if ... then ...set css or insert dom element );
```

The other way has been suggested by Luiggi and is probably closer to the JSF spirit.

Comment: I though this as a possible answer too but I don't have an IDE in my workplace to make the tests =\ (well, I have an IDE but I can't use the work laptop for that =\).